# Nattable: I need help to paste the formate of the cell also in Nattable

Tags: nattable

I have devlop copy paste function for Nattable but not able to paste the format like size and color of the text or background.I tried copyhandler for copy paste.Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Styling and data handling is completely separated in NatTable concepts. So it could be from very easy to quite complicated dependent on your styling implementation. If you use conditional styling the styles should be applied automatically. If you store the styling information with some custom approach, you need to find a way to copy that kind of meta data together with the data to the clipboard.